# How to use hadoop to process just a part of data

Tags: hadoop

I'm a newbie in hadoop and I met a trouble: some data will be stored in hadoop everyday, and I do some processings at the same time. These processings may use all of the data, or may be just a part of them(like just deal with today's data), what is the best way to implement this?

Should I generate a single file for one day, or just one file from the start to the end? I think hadoop  doesn't have a 'filter' mechanism like 'query' in mongodb, so if I just want to process today's data, is it a waste to go through all the data?

Any advice will help, Thx!

Comment: what is type of data? Structured Or unstructured or semi structured? What is the source? FIle or RDBMS or NoSQL? Depending on type of data, solution can be provided.

Comment: Thx for help and sorry for my late... My data is structured(json), line-based. Now it's keeped in mongodb, but I can export it into a file or split it into sevaral files... That means I can control the type and size of source.